# (Android-O) App not listed in 'apps with usage access' but is in Nougat

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

In Android-O the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />` doesn't seem to enable the app to show up in the 'Apps with usage access' list.
I have tried setting the target & compile API to both 25 & 'O' but still it doesn't enable me to add app to the usage access list.

I'm not sure if it is just because the dev preview is buggy, or google have additional requirements for this functionality in Android-O. But it shows up on my nougat test device when I test it on there, of course both the compile & target are set to 25 on there, hence I tried those settings on the Android-O device to check if it is the OS or the SDK that is at fault, it seems that it may be the OS though.
Anyway, I thought I should ask on here to see if I am missing something that you guys & girls might be aware of.

Comment: Check the Merged Manifest sub-tab in the manifest editor in Android Studio, and see if your `<uses-permission>` shows up there. You might also try `aapt dump badging` and see if the permission shows up there.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, it does show up in the merged manifest. Though I don't see it in the 'aapt dump badging'...

Comment: Hmmm... even with `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` set to 25, and the app working on older versions of Android?

Comment: Yeah... I've got both my Nexus 5 (Hammerhead) & Nexus 6P with me, (The N5 has a custom nougat rom btw), and when I test the Compile/Target 25 on there with the same code, it shows up in the apps usage list, but it doesn't show up when set to 'O' or '25' on the 6P (Running Android-O - DP1). Although the 6P did show it when running N a few days ago.

Comment: OK, perhaps that permission is handled differently by `aapt dump badging` then. Traditional permissions show up, and if the functionality is working on Android 7.x but `aapt dump badging` doesn't show the permission, then that particular test didn't work. :-( If you create a reproducible test case, [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190602%20status:open), as I don't know what else to suggest at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's not too important as it is just for a product designed to show Androids capabilities to a few people: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLr7EtAgCKU&t

Comment: I raised an issue and according to the Google developer assigned to it, the problem will be resolved in the next Android O build. See issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37056459

Comment: @prajitdas: Thanks for taking your time to let us know about this! Its Nice to know that this bug will be gone in the next build! :)